# SED or AWK to remove everything before the first dash and after the last

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, command-line

I have a private key file with some extra nonsense in there, and want just the text of the key.

so:

```
nonsense -----Begin Key-----
keep this1
keep this2 
keep this3
-----End Key----- nonsense
```

should become

```
-----Begin Key-----
keep this1
keep this2 
keep this3
-----End Key-----
```

EDIT: I don't want to just remove the actual word "nonsense." It could be anything in there before and after the key text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
sed -e '/Begin Key/ s/^[^-]*//' -e '/End Key/ s/[^-]*$//'
```

Ex.

```
$ sed -e '/Begin Key/ s/^[^-]*//' -e '/End Key/ s/[^-]*$//' file
-----Begin Key-----
keep this1
keep this2 
keep this3
-----End Key-----
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/-----(Begin Key|End Key)-----/{sub(/^[^\-]+|[^\-]+$/, "")}1' data
```

- `/-----(Begin Key|End Key)-----/` find begin or end key line
- `{sub(/^[^\-]+|[^\-]+$/, "")}` clear leading and trailing nonsense.
- `1` always print